# How to process all #include directives in Visual Studio C++ 2005?

Tags: c++, compilation, include, visual-studio-2005, c-preprocessor

I want to see how my #include files be processed when Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compile it.
As I remember, there is a compile option to inline all #includes and #define lines but I can't find it.
I use MSVC 2005 sp1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you are looking for is under your project properties, "C/C++", "Preprocessor" then change "Generate Preprocessed File" to "With Line Numbers" or "Without Line Numbers", whatever you want.